# List vs LinkedList vs ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list

On which basis should we choose to use List, LinkedList, ArrayList in Java?.

Also please explain which one is better to use?.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `List` is an interface, whereas `ArrayList` (and `LinkedList`) are _an implementation_ of a `List`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refer to the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and when needed, how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can try to help you with a problem. You're often expected to do your own homework and research before asking a question.

Comment: Note that Java's implementation of linked list is limited. There is no equivalent to C++ std::list::splice(), which is used to move nodes within or between lists. Java's linked list iterators can't be shallow copied, assignment just creates another pointer to the same iterator object. If something is inserted or removed from a linked list, than all iterators to that list are invalidated (or all but the iterator used to do the insert or delete). It's better to create your own linked list class due to these issues.

Answer (score 1):

`List` is an interface, it should be the type of your variables or the arguments of your methods.

The other two are implementations of this interface.

`LinkedList` is optimized for inserts and deletes.

`ArrayList` is optimized for random access.

So, you can choose based on the kind of work you are going to do.

Comment: In theory `LinkedList` is optimized for insert and deletes, but in practice using an `ArrayList` is almost always going to perform better.